# Selecting customer IDs who have purchased from a certain channel

Tags: sql

I'm trying to pull a list of customer IDs who have purchased online *only* and another list of those who have purchased *both* online and in-store (no customers for in-store only). I currently have a table that looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
**customerid**        **shipped_dt**        **channel**
1                       2018-10-31            online
1                       2018-11-01            store
2                       2018-11-01            store
3                       2018-11-01            online
3                       2018-11-02            online
```

In this case, for the list with those who have purchased both online and in-store, I was customerid 1. For the list of customers that are online only, I want customerid 3. How exactly would I go about writing a code for this? I'm still learning SQL so I'm not too knowledgeable about the proper syntax and abilities within SQL.

I only want a return of customerid and the channel that they purchased through.

Thank you!

Comment: How would you go about it? Add to the question what you have tried.

Comment: which dbms you are using (mysql, postgresql, oracle, tsql)?

Comment: @Student  What have you tried?  Since you are learning, a good strategy would be to attempt to do this by yourself.  Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a separate list of customers, you might want to use `exists`:

For example, to get customers who have purchased in both places:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where exists (select 1 from t where t.customer_id = c.customer_id and t.channel = 'online'
             ) and
      exists (select 1 from t where t.customer_id = c.customer_id and t.channel = 'store'
             ) ;
```

This can have some advantages over aggregation:

- `exists` and `not exists` can make direct use of an index on `(customer_id, store)`.
- You can get customers who purchased in *neither* channel.
- You can get additional information about the customer, if that is desirable.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was a great straightforward way of getting what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor alternative

**Example**

```
Select customerid 
      ,Channel  = min(Channel)
 From  YourTable
 Group By customerid
 Having min(Channel)=max(channel)
    and min(Channel)='online'
```

Note: If you remove `and min(Channel)='online'` you would see customers who purchased through only one channel

**Returns**

```
customerid  Channel
3           online
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case of `'online'` only customers use `not exists` to exclude those who have purchased in `'store'`:

```
select distinct customerid 
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename where customerid = t.customerid and channel = 'store'
)
```

For the case of `'online'` and `'store'`:

```
select distinct customerid 
from tablename t
where 
  (select count(distinct channel) from tablename where customerid = t.customerid) = 2
```

You can combine the above queries into this:

```
select distinct customerid, 'online' channel
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename where customerid = t.customerid and channel = 'store'
)
union all
select distinct customerid, 'both' channel
from tablename t
where 
  (select count(distinct channel) from tablename where customerid = t.customerid) = 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6dc140e3c0b2b1fc9b6c9a94a728b616)